# Deleting User in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create an admin area where the admin can delete a user from `dbo.AspNetUsers`. So far I have this in my index view from my admin controller:

```
@using BlogMaxim.Models
@model List<BlogMaxim.Models.Users>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@foreach (Users user in Model)
{
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Id</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@user.UserName</td>
                <td>@user.Email</td>
                <td>@user.Id</td>
                <td>@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Admin", new { id = user.Id }))
                {
                    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Delete" />
                }</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

}
```

It shows all the users along with a delete button next to it. I do not know what code I need to write in my admincontroller's `Delete` method:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private UserRepository repoUsers = new UserRepository();

    // GET: Admin
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Users> users = repoUsers.GetUsers();
        return View(users);
    }

    public ActionResult Delete()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

This is what I have at this time, I'm rather new to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @AwaisMahmood Yes I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using EF then its more simpler as:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int Id)
{
    private ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();  
    var user = context.Users.Find(Id);
    context.Users.Remove(user);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

where ApplicationDbContext is the child class of IdentityDbContext placed in IdentityModels.cs in Models folder

Comment: Does this 'ABC' in your example represents my list "Users" (my model)?

Comment: I don't understand the 'db' part? Where does this come from? I forgot to add that I want to delete the users in my Database 'dbo.AspNetUsers'

Comment: Ok, but how does mvc know that it has to delete from that dbo? I also get these errors, http://puu.sh/mj8WM/f4d45bb409.png

Comment: MVC will know it from your DbContext instance.. For your personal Entities/Models you have a separate instance

Comment: The errors are gone but when clicking on 'Delete'
I get this error saying that Id is 0 The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Delete(Int32)' in 'BlogMaxim.Controllers.AdminController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: its because the controller method is expecting an "Id" as a parameter.

Comment: Fixed it, it was because the Id was a string in my model and I gave it as a int parameter in my controller.

Comment: ha.. we all make this kind of idiotic mistakes :)... Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Create a dbEntities class-

```
public partial class dbEntities : DbContext
    {
        public dbEntities()
            : base("name=the name of the database that you have given in connectionstring")
        {
        }
}
```

In the controller -

```
private readonly dbEntities database;
 public AdminController ()
        {
            this.database = new dbEntities();
        }
```

Then in your ActionResult of Delete

```
public ActionResult Delete(int Id)
{
    ABC abc = new ABC();
    abc = db.ABC.Find(Id);
    database.Remove(abc);
    database.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```